# Replace string between tags if string begins with "1"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a huge XML file (about 100MB) and each line contains something along the lines of `<tag>10005991</tag>`. So for example:

```
textextextextext<tag>10005991<tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005992</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>10005993</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005994</tag>textextextextext
```

I want to replace any string between the tags and that begins with "1" to be replaced with a string of my choice and then write back to the file. I've tried using the line.replace function which works but only if I specify the string.

```
line=line.replace("<tag>10005991</tag>","<tag>YYYYYY</tag>")
```

Ideal output:

```
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY<tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005992</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005994</tag>textextextextext
```

I've thought about using an array to pass each string in and then replace but I'm sure there's a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> text = 'textextextextext<tag>10005991</tag>textextextextext'
>>> re.sub(r'<tag>1(\d+)</tag>','<tag>YYYYY</tag>',text)
'textextextextext<tag>YYYYY</tag>textextextextext'
```

`re.sub` will replace the matched text with the second argument.

Quote from the doc

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged.

Usage may be like:

```
with open("file") as f:
    for i in f:
       with open("output") as f2:
           f2.write(re.sub(r'<tag>1(\d+)</tag>','<tag>YYYYY</tag>',i))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex but as you have a multi-line string you need to use [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag ,  and in your pattern you can use [positive look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for match string between tags:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<=<tag>)1\d+(?=</?tag>)',r'YYYYYY',s,re.DOTALL,re.MULTILINE)
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY<tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005992</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005994</tag>textextextextext
```

> re.DOTALL
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Also as @Bhargav Rao have did in his answer you can use grouping instead look-around :

```
>>> print re.sub(r'<tag>(1\d+)</?tag>',r'<tag>YYYYYY</?tag>',s,re.DOTALL,re.MULTILINE)
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY</?tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005992</tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>YYYYYY</?tag>textextextextext
textextextextext<tag>20005994</tag>textextextextext
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use  [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

The main idea:
1) Parse the file
2) Find the elements value
3) Test your condition
4) Replace value if condition met

Here is a good place to start parsing : [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python?rq=1)